# GET URL 500 (Internal Server Error) - Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internal-server-error, express-handlebars

I have an **Internal Server Error** on my website

When I write in console **heroku logs -t** I get this

```
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151925+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: view.render is not a function
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151942+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryRender (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151946+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151946+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151947+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/routes/index.js:35:7
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151948+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151948+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151948+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151949+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151949+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2020-11-10T00:22:21.151950+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

my index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.get("/public/products/bags.json", function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  });
  res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
});
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("constructor", { //<---------THIS --- at /app/routes/index.js:35:7
    style: "constructor",
    bags: data,
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const routes = require("./routes/index");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.use("/", routes);
app.listen(PORT);
```

when I use my webserver it's ok. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: attach your `package.json` and `Procfile` contents

Comment: @StefanWang Sorry for taking so long - package.json -
```
{
  "name": "one",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery-pjax": "^2.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.15",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

```

Comment: will you please upload your node version too?

Comment: @StefanWang  node -v
v14.15.0

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the node version mismatch between your local environment and the Heroku environment. You should specify the node version in your package.json to let Heroku know the correct node version.

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "one",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery-pjax": "^2.0.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.15",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",

    "engines": {
        "node": "14.x"
    },
}
```

Comment: but after rewrite package.json, I have GET "URL" 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Don't you use Procfile?

Comment: No, without Procfile, I have similar nodejs project with deloy on Heroku, that's project works

Comment: I still have Internal Server Error :(